# What is the best place to setup system wide environment variables on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, environment-variables

I just want to setup a system wide environment variable, `JAVA_HOME` for **all users, including root** user.

Requirements:

- accessible to normal users
- accessible to root
- always loaded, not only for bash (gnome-terminal does not start a bash by default)
- to work on Ubuntu, Debian and optionally Red Hat
- great if addition could be easily scripted

Comment: For interactive shells check this [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/438170/47839) thread out.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

For Ubuntu, and possibly other *nix platforms, add a new script in `/etc/profile.d` named `java.sh`, such as:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java" > /etc/profile.d/java.sh
```

Other considerations that were ruled out:

- `/etc/environment` - works but is harder to maintain using other tools (or people will edit it); and
- `/etc/profile` - same drawbacks as `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 13):

On Debian/Ubuntu that would be [/etc/environment](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

I don't know the Red Hat equivalent.

Comment: I believe /etc/environment is deprecated

Comment: @PatJames do you have more info about this? I tried /etc/environment is is not loaded for root even after I rebooted the machine.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea some info is here:  https://wiki.debian.org/Locale indicating /etc/environment is no longer used in newer releases

Comment: That page only says that you shouldn't but locale related variables in `/etc/environment`. See also http://serverfault.com/a/584072/26218

Answer (score 12):

I don't understand why you ruled out /etc/profile.  That is the correct location.

Answer (score 12):

A few have answered saying that `/etc/environment` is depricated and/or not used in Debian anymore, and this is (as at version 7) false.

The file is actually read by PAM -- specifically, `pam_env(8)`, via a default to the `envfile` flag.  The manpage also states this default under the FILES section.

The wikis quoted (especially the locale one) merely state that locale-based environment variables are now meant to be in `/etc/profile`.  Their statement "(in older versions of Debian, also /etc/environment)" is vague, and is in the context of locales.

A quick grep through `/etc/pam.d` shows:

```
root@box:/etc/pam.d# grep pam_env.so *
atd:auth        required        pam_env.so
cron:session       required   pam_env.so
cron:session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
login:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
sshd:auth       required     pam_env.so # [1]
sshd:auth       required     pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1
su:session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

Those config lines are additive, and as the first is missing `envfile`, it thus defaults to `/etc/environment`.

All of this, of course, relies on whatever binary you're using (`crond`, login shells etc) are compiled against PAM.

Finally, this implies that other systems using PAM (eg RedHat), behave the same, as can be seen in it's respective manpage.

Comment: For what it's worth.. now some 7 years later. All the docs I find point to /etc/environments being, not a good idea to edit directly. Placing a bash script in /etc/profile.d being the preferred method, although something I've found odd.. maybe it's normal. None of the .sh's in here have the executable flag set.

Answer (score 3):

One a side note: Have a look at the [Modules Environment](http://modules.sourceforge.net/). I use this every time I have to offer a complex, versioned, self-extensible, concise UNIX environment to dozens or hundreds of users. It's mainly used on large scale multi-user HPC environments. Just using it for one particular variable is certainly over-engineering it, but it does an awesome job once you need more than a few software packages and their environment.

Answer (score 3):

`/etc/enviroment` is no used in the last debian stable release. The recomendation is create your own `*.sh` file in `/etc/profile.d/` for this porpuose as Sorin S saids. See https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables

Comment: At https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables we can read the opposite: "Put all global environment variables, i.e. ones affecting all users, into /etc/environment"

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/profile` should work. I tested just now to be sure, put `export SOMETEST=1234` to `/etc/profile` and after re-logging `echo $SOMETEST` gave me `1234` as expected. Also from `gnome-terminal`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any ~ specific files in this case. so....

`/etc/profile` would be the proper place for it in this case. Current logged in users have to get a new login session though, but this should not be that big of a problem.

@wk01: `/etc/profile` is not loaded by a nonlogin shell by default. your `.bashrc`  is probably loading it...